# OpenCL Programm freezes everytime private variables used

Tags: opencl

I got a kernel method, simplified looks like this.

```
__kernel void calculate (__global float *a, __global float *b, __global int *res) {
    int workItem = get_global_id(0); // Syntax may not right, but you get the idea
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<100000000; i++) {
        float c = a[i]*3;
        float d = b[i]*2;

        if (c<d) {
            found++;
        }
    }
    res[workItem]= found;
}
```

So, nothing much but simple calculation and a very big loop, the problem is the programm freezes all the time when i run this code. **I have to force reset the computer everytime this happens.**
But if i make some changes, like this

```
if (true) {
    found++;
}
```

Or

```
if (1<2) {
    found++
}
```

Then the programm works like a charm, and very fast! So i wonder if is there any thing wrong with variables c and d ? I tried to use things like

```
__private float c= ..;
__private float d= ..;
```

It didnt work either.

I read the return code of every step while creating programm and kernel, so its not the problem.

What did I do wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues here.

1. You are running a giant loop, presumably with a single work item, which is exactly what you want to avoid in OpenCL, as the entire concept of parallelism is lost.  OpenCL will not magically make your code fast if you don't use it correctly.
2. Even if you are using multiple work items, you are not making use of the value you retrieve from `get_global_id()` except for output.  But, as they're all using the same input, you'll get the same output for every single work item!

Work items and their associated global IDs are intended to allow you to partition your processing into discrete units, rather than one big monolithic loop.  I suggest you look at some tutorials like [this one](https://anteru.net/blog/2012/11/04/2016/index.html) to understand the concept better.  Don't start writing your own code until you understand his.

As for why your program freezes your PC, I can only speculate without seeing your host code.  Perhaps you are getting [buffer overrun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)?

Comment: Hi, about the issues, i  understand what you mean, keep that in mind its just a simple code snippet, my actual code is not like this. I have to do this giant loop like 200 times.

So the problem is the buffer overrun, like you said, I am trying to figure out which.

One question, is the cost of calling another kernel function, set all arguments.. high ? I  am considering decompose this into more than 1 kernel function.